# What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to import into woocommerce using wp all import

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to import photos of products with the help of wp import.

I imported all products without pictures as draft. Now publishes products that interest me. However, when I do a separate import of only photos, a photo of the first product is set in each product.

sku I set as id and based on it I do import product updates.

What am I doing wrong? Xml structure:

```xml
    <p>
    <id>620</id>
    <name></name>
    <reference></reference>
    <ean13></ean13>
    <stock>8</stock>
    <price>
    <tax>23</tax>
    <netto>434.82</netto>
    <brutto>534.83</brutto>
    </price>
    <weight unit="kg">0</weight>
    <manufacturer>Step2</manufacturer>
    <description></description>
    <description_short></description_short>
    <cat id="12"></cat>
    <catsub id="16"></catsub>
    <catsub id="24"></catsub>
    <catsub id="62"></catsub>
    <catsub id="101"></catsub>
    <images>
    <img></img>
    <img></img>
    <img></img>
    <img></img>
    </images>
    <features>
    <f></f>
    <f></f>
    <f></f>
    <f></f>
    </features>
    </p>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOxOU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6iGH.png)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, how do you do 'import' images?

Comment: I use wp all import and file from xml warehouse.
Pictures in the file are saved as links:
  <Images>
     <Img> https://warehouse.com/img1.png </ img>
     <Img> https://warehouse.com/img2.png </ img>
     <Img> https://warehouse.com/img3.png </ img>
     <Img> https://warehouse.com/im4.png </ img>
     </ Images>

I am using the option to update existing products.

Comment: Why don't you use the admin area, when you log in your-domain.com/wp-admin/?  The WooCommerce plugin, on the left sidebar, has an area called 'Products'.  Have you done it that way?

Comment: This is the most I can use, but why should I do it manually?
I only have xml and csv not. Woocomerce doesn't use xml.
WP all import does everything for me and enables automatic refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this plugin in WP, however, there is a video on it by the people who created the 'WP All Import' software and they say, if you have questions, you can contact their support.

There also are videos by them on YouTube, if it is going to help on here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Slqm1CHmAZQ

Their website has a number of samples and explanations, see if you can first find your solution here:  http://www.wpallimport.com/woocommerce-product-import/

I hope this helps.